# H.323 client for Linux that can broadcast screen?

Tags: linux, conferencing

I'm looking for an application for Linux that will connect to an H.323 video conference and allow the user to send their desktop as a video stream, instead of using the image from a webcam. This is for giving presentations, when it is usually more useful to see the speaker's slides than their face.

All I have found so far is Ekiga, but as far as I can see it doesn't offer this facility. Something free would be nice of course, but paid-for software would also be of interest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about using a virtual webcam? [WebcamStudio](http://www.ws4gl.org/) is capable of creating a virtual webcam from the desktop. You can then just use Ekiga or any other application to conference.

Comment: Thanks Jamie. That is probably the way to go. Unfortunately I have not been able to compile the "vloopback" driver on our Linux distribution (Scientific Linux CERN 5, a clone of RHEL5). Maybe this will have to wait until we have a release with a newer kernel. Suggestions of other virtual webcams are welcome, but I haven't yet found any that look promising.